# shelljs.exec(`sudo pkill -P ${process.pid}` did not work in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, shelljs, pkill

I have a python module that work with webcam by opencv in ubuntu. I should execute it from nodejs so I use shelljs package and run `shell.exec('sudo pkill -P ${pythonProcess.pid}')`. It does not close webcam otherwise it working in terminal of ubuntu. I type `sudo pkill -P <PID>` in terminal and process is terminated and close webcam immediately. anybody has any idea why? tnx.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nodejs, and as such shelljs, but what happens if you run sudo shell.exec(...)?
Or is that not even possible?
If shell.exec is a command within the script then maybe the script needs su permission first?

Comment: sorry for my bad explain. shell.exec is a instruction of shelljs package of nodejs. and I run it in nodejs. It runs system script in a shell of OS.  pkill command in ubuntu needs su permission so I pass script string to shelljs.exec with sudo. Should I take su permission to shelljs package or nodejs?

Comment: Do you have to enter a password to run `sudo pkill -P <PID>`?

Comment: Where is `pythonProcess.pid` defined and does it contain the correct PID?

Comment: @r.a.shehni Try su permission with both? I'll step back from helping you on this since I'm unfamiliar with nodejs. Good luck.

Comment: no I have not. I setting up it on NOPASS.@ThomasSablik

Comment: pythonProcess is created by another shelljs.exec(...) instruction and yes its PID is correct because when I type sudo pkill -P by pythonProcess.pid, this command is terminated process and close webcam window .@tripleee